# How can I launch an ACTION_VOICE_COMMAND Intent from a Service?

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-intent

I have the following code to launch an Intent in my service:

```
Intent voiceCommandIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VOICE_COMMAND);
            voiceCommandIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            appContext.startActivity(voiceCommandIntent);
```

I get the error

```
No Activity Found to Handle Intent
```

Here is the stacktrace:

```
03-07 20:12:56.796: W/System.err(18401): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VOICE_COMMAND flg=0x10000000 }
03-07 20:12:56.796: I/ActivityManager(1120): Starting activity: Intent { act=android.intent.action.VOICE_COMMAND flg=0x10000000 }
03-07 20:12:56.802: W/System.err(18401):    at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1408)
03-07 20:12:56.802: W/System.err(18401):    at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1378)
03-07 20:12:56.802: W/System.err(18401):    at android.app.ContextImpl.startActivity(ContextImpl.java:649)
03-07 20:12:56.802: W/System.err(18401):    at android.content.ContextWrapper.startActivity(ContextWrapper.java:258)
03-07 20:12:56.802: W/System.err(18401):    at com.sonrlabs.test.sonr.UserActionHandler.processUserCommand(UserActionHandler.java:153)
03-07 20:12:56.802: W/System.err(18401):    at com.sonrlabs.test.sonr.UserActionHandler.processAction(UserActionHandler.java:72)
03-07 20:12:56.802: W/System.err(18401):    at com.sonrlabs.test.sonr.AudioProcessorQueue.handleAction(AudioProcessorQueue.java:54)
03-07 20:12:56.802: W/System.err(18401):    at com.sonrlabs.test.sonr.AudioProcessorQueue.processAction(AudioProcessorQueue.java:33)
03-07 20:12:56.802: W/System.err(18401):    at com.sonrlabs.test.sonr.signal.SignalConstructor.processSignalIfMatch(SignalConstructor.java:50)
03-07 20:12:56.802: W/System.err(18401):    at com.sonrlabs.test.sonr.signal.TransmissionFinder.processSample(TransmissionFinder.java:29)
03-07 20:12:56.802: W/System.err(18401):    at com.sonrlabs.test.sonr.signal.TransmissionFinder.nextSample(TransmissionFinder.java:23)
03-07 20:12:56.802: W/System.err(18401):    at com.sonrlabs.test.sonr.signal.TransmissionPreprocessor.nextSample(TransmissionPreprocessor.java:38)
03-07 20:12:56.802: W/System.err(18401):    at com.sonrlabs.test.sonr.signal.AudioProcessor.nextSamples(AudioProcessor.java:22)
03-07 20:12:56.802: W/System.err(18401):    at com.sonrlabs.test.sonr.AudioProcessorQueue.run(AudioProcessorQueue.java:82)
```

I just want the Android Voice Command Prompt to appear. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that noone in your "device" is able to handle that Intent with Action ACTION_VOICE_COMMAND.

The code you posted is ok. That's the right way of launching Intents from a Service.

Comment: Here's an easy way to tell if there is a receiver for your intent: http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/can-i-use-this-intent.html

Comment: Do I need to add an intent filter in my Manifest for ACTION_VOICE_COMMAND?

Answer (score 2):

You should simply broadcast the intent. then the system grabs it and starts the Voice command app.
    Intent broadcast = new Intent();
    broadcast.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VOICE_COMMAND);
    sendBroadcast(broadcast);